# javax.net.ssl does not exist when trying to build with jdk 1.8

Tags: java, ssl, libraries

I am trying to mess around with SSL and have attempted to include the package javax.net.ssl. When I compile Eclipse tells me that this package does not exist.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm not including any explicit dependency in maven for this as I believe it is supposed to be in the basic JDK...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile 
(default-compile) on project SSLTest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] package javax.net.ssl does not exist
```